# Some Python comment are white color when using vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

when I typing python in vscode, some commands or keywords(such as while in this picture) have marked with white.

[image]

However, in some cases, the comments after the words are printed normally.

[image]

Also, some commands are colored in white in the front of file, but sometimes it is printed normally in the same file's back.

what's the problem in my vscode and python?

Comment: Please cut and paste the real code into the question, not screen captures of code.

Comment: This problem is not a code, it is a problem of color. If I wrote down the code, there's no problem, and you don't know exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Vscode will make a visual difference between simple comments (colored in white) and class/function descriptor (colored in orange)

Comment: The error seems to have occurred using type hinting. Thank you for your comment